# How to replace Toolbar Title with CustomView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, toolbar, layout-inflater

how can i replace the title in a toolbar with a custom layout View? And then i want to remove that view when i dismiss it. So i only want that view to be in the toolbar in one fragment.

i was trying this but it doesn't work:

```
activity.supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
activity.supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
activity.supportActionBar!!.customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_segmented_control, null, false)
```

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: @mcflysoft yes look at the answer i posted now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the solution:

```kotlin
val activity = activity ?: return
val mainActivity = activity as MainActivity

mainActivity.supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)
mainActivity.supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)

mainActivity.supportActionBar?.customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_segmented_control, null, false)
segmentedControl = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_segmented_control, null, false)
segmentedControl.segmented_control.notifyConfigIsChanged()

val toolbar = mainActivity.findViewById<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
toolbar.addView(segmentedControl, toolbar.childCount)
```